# Nginx Request header Or Cookie Too Large

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, unicorn

I am trying to setup Nginx + Unicorn + Rails 3. Nginx will also serve some static and php projects. However when I open the site I always see a

```
400 Bad Request
Request Header Or Cookie Too Large
```

error page. Nothing in the access nor error logs.

/etc/nginx

nginx.conf https://gist.github.com/1117152

php.conf https://gist.github.com/1117154

drop.conf https://gist.github.com/1117158

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled

https://gist.github.com/1117161

I am pretty stuck here because I don't see anything in logs.

Comment: Does it happen on development mode? Did you check if you're adding way too many objects in the session?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hmm of course it's the users fault. I had a wrong references to the socket in the site-available conf and an endless loop was the result. I fixed it in the gist.

Answer (score 3):

Check your "large_client_header_buffers". You might need to use a larger value if your application require

Answer (score 0):

This came high up on Google so to save time for people in the same situation:

I included the JavaScript FB_Init (Facebook) on a page and had the "cookie=true" which produced an amazingly big cookie. Turning this to false was the solution and resolved the identical message.